# How do i be good at making commands in minecraft, I really want to make a good adventure map, its my first time!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So me have recently had an idea to make an adventure map and me have started making it but me have ran into a problem.... I cant script very well, if someone that is good at making commands please help me, you can add me on discord at: B r a z i l#2870

Comment: Sorry, this is not a general forum, this is a Q&A site. Minecraft Commands is a topic one can write a book about.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips for you:
This is the list of targets:

@p = closest player

@a = all players

@e = all entities

@r = random player

@s = the player who runs the command.

{player name} = that player.

These are some basic commands:

/give {One of the targets from the list above} {item} {amount} - this gives an item to the player you tell it to give it to.

/kill {target} - kills that player you instruct it to.

/summon minecraft:{entity} - summons that entity.

/setblock {where etc. 0 5 0} {block type} - This summons a block at that position.

/tp {target} {where (like 12 5 0 or another player)}

There are more, but these are the ones I know. I hope this helps and you make a cool map!